Failing to start a local Flyte cluster
I am trying to run a project locally following the tutorial Running a workflow in a local Flyte cluster.
However when running flytectl demo start I get the following error:
‍ Bootstrapping a brand new Flyte cluster...   Error: Malformed version: flytectl/v0.8.20 {"json":{},"level":"error","msg":"Malformed version: flytectl/v0.8.20","ts":"2024-05-16T15:27:30+02:00"}
Any idea about what could be wrong ?
It is run on an Ubuntu 22.04.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

This was caused by the recent flytectl migration to the monorepo.
You can either use your package manager to upgrade flytectl and fix the malformed version, or bootstrap your cluster using:
flytectl demo start --version v1.12.0

Let us know if that helps
